# Checking all radio button are checked in native javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a gatherRadioBtn() function which posts form else displays error in page. This takes cue from checkRadioWrapper() to check if all radio buttons are checked.

However, the `true` condition does not materialize. Is there a mistake in my `(r[i].type == "radio") && !(r[i].checked)` expression.

Will upload on jsfiddle soon

Thanks.

```
function checkRadioWrapper()
{
    for (var i=0; i < r.length; i++)
    {
        if (  (r[i].type == "radio") && !(r[i].checked) )
        {
            return false;   
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function gatherRadioBtn()
{
    alert("in gather");
    var r = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var literal = [];

    for (var i=0; i < r.length; i++)
    {
        if (  (r[i].type == "radio") && r[i].checked )
        {
            literal.push(r[i].name);
            literal.push(r[i].value);
        }
    }

    if (checkRadioWrapper())
    {
        document.getElementById("Errnodata").innerHTML = "" ;  
        var joinedArray = literal.join(", ");
        window.opener.document.getElementById("myarray").value= joinedArray;
        window.opener.getVolunteerDetails();
        window.close();
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("Errnodata").innerHTML = "Please select for every radio btns!" ;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a `var r = document.getElementsByTagName("input");` is needed in the wrapper function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass "r" as a parameter to your function:

```
function checkRadioWrapper( r )
{
    for (var i=0; i < r.length; i++)
      // etc
```

and then:

```
if (checkRadioWrapper( r ))
```

Now, that said, in a group of radio buttons sharing the same name, the browser will never allow all of them to be checked at the same time. Thus, this really doesn't make a lot of sense. If you've got radio buttons that don't share a name with other radio buttons, they should be checkboxes and not radio buttons.

Comment: They are named differently. By the way, your solution helps; thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome!  And as I wrote above, if you have radio buttons with all different names, then they should probably be checkboxes instead.